# Excel VBA Loop Through a Range of Cells to Insert a Shape Based on an If Statement

Tags: vba, excel, loops, if-statement

I'm trying to add an upside down red triangle to a cell to indicate a decrease in performance. For instance whenever cell B5 is less than 0, insert the upside down red triangle into cell B3.
I've managed to get the shape to insert into B3 if B5 is less than zero, but I now need to do this for cells C3 & C5, D3 & D5, E3 & E5, all the way through column M, possibly more. Not only that but it is likely I'll need to do this for more rows further down my spreadsheet as well.
How can I make my Macro loop through each row and column so that it checks if a cell is less than zero then it will add an upside down red triangle to cell (row,column)?

```
 Sub Add_negative_Triangle()


'Adds Red Triangle to a Cell to indicate a decrease when corresponding cell if of a certain value

    Dim SSLeft As Double
    Dim SSRight As Double
    Dim SSTop As Double
    Dim SSWidth As Double
    Dim SSHeight As Double
    Dim SS As Range, N As Long
    Dim z As Integer
    Dim shpIsoscelesTriangle As Shape
    Set SS = Range("B3:M3")
    z = 0
    SSLeft = SS.Left
    SSTop = SS.Top
    SSHeight = SS.Height
    SSWidth = SS.Width



  If Range("B5:M5") <= z Then
        ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeIsoscelesTriangle, SSLeft, SSTop, 11, 13).Select

    End If


 If Range("B5:M5") <= z Then
 With Selection.ShapeRange.Fill
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(205, 0, 0)
        .Transparency = 0
        .Solid
 End With



                                            End If

If Range("B5:M5") <= z Then


With Selection.ShapeRange.Line
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(205, 0, 0)
        .Transparency = 0
    End With
                                            End If


Selection.ShapeRange.Rotation = 180
Selection.ShapeRange.IncrementLeft 1.5
Selection.ShapeRange.IncrementTop 1.5





End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

This will add your triangle shape to every cell in `B5:M5` where the cell two rows above has negative value. You can apply it to any range actually (starting from row 3).

```
Sub Add_negative_Triangle()
    Dim ss As Range, shp As Shape
    For Each ss In ActiveSheet.Range("B5:M5")
        If ss.offset(-2).value < 0 Then
            Set shp = ss.Parent.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeIsoscelesTriangle, ss.Left, ss.Top, 11, 13)
            With shp.Fill
                .Visible = msoTrue
                .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(205, 0, 0)
                .Transparency = 0
                .Solid
            End With
            With shp.line
                .Visible = msoTrue
                .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(205, 0, 0)
                .Transparency = 0
            End With
            shp.Rotation = 180
            shp.IncrementLeft 1.5
            shp.IncrementTop 1.5
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Beat me to it. Took me a while to figure out that ShapeRange was causing errors.

Comment: @user3598756, yes, starting from row 3. I added that detail, thanks.

Comment: These solutions both worked out very nicely. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Sub Add_negative_Triangle()

'Adds Red Triangle to a Cell to indicate a decrease when corresponding cell if of a certain value

    Dim SSLeft As Double
    Dim SSRight As Double
    Dim SSTop As Double
    Dim SSWidth As Double
    Dim SSHeight As Double
    Dim SS As Range, N As Long
    Dim z As Integer
    Dim shpIsoscelesTriangle As Shape
    Dim r As Range
    Dim s As Shape

    Set SS = Range("B3:M3")
    z = 0

    For Each r In SS
        SSLeft = r.Left
        SSTop = r.Top
        SSHeight = r.Height
        SSWidth = r.Width

        If r.Offset(2) <= z Then
            Set s = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeIsoscelesTriangle, SSLeft, SSTop, 11, 13)
            With s.Fill
               .Visible = msoTrue
               .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(205, 0, 0)
               .Transparency = 0
               .Solid
            End With
            With s.Line
                .Visible = msoTrue
                .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(205, 0, 0)
                .Transparency = 0
            End With
            s.Rotation = 180
            s.IncrementLeft 1.5
            s.IncrementTop 1.5
        End If
    Next r

End Sub
```